# Logic App SAP Connector - SAP running in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, sap-erp, netweaver

I'm doing some initial research using Azure Logic Apps to use SAP connector to connect to a system.  Everything I've read is connecting to a SAP on-premise system.  In this case, SAP software is running in Azure.

Can I still use the SAP connector?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems your question is more suited for https://serverfault.com , try that site or ask SAP support!

Answer (score 0):

In short yes, According to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-sap-connector#sap-compatibility), SAP connector operates with both on-premises and cloud-based SAP HANA systems.